# Create a PDF when an item is approved

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, power-automate, pdf

I'm trying to automate a SharePoint site, so that when an item is approved, a PDF will be automatically created.

The PDF will be based on an existing template and when an item is approved, I want to automatically replace/add certain strings in the template with data from the item.

I've been looking everywhere and tried messing with SP Designer but for some reason my version of Designer lacks the workflow actions that are needed to create PDFs...

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: @GaneshSanap SharePoint 2013

Answer (score -1):

If the existing template is created HTML then you can use File Convert in power automate to convert it to pdf after tweaking the HTML file. The file convert isn't perfect and usually works fine with basic html code, for complicated HTML files you might need to use a 3rd party paid tool like Encodian.

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: @theking Why would the template be HTML if I want it to be a PDF file? I need a free solution with little to no 3rd party tools.